# Making HTML li elements wrap like sentences in a paragraph

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I would like to have text list elements wrap like sentences in a paragraph. Here is the HTML & CSS, as well as a code snippet that illustrates how if a `li` element is longer than the width of the `ul` container, it starts on a new line.

```css
    ul {
        width: 100%;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    li, h2 {
        display: inline-block;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    
    li::after {
    content: '\00a0 '; /* To give a space between li elements */
    }
```

```html
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h2>Hello!</h2>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>How are you?</h2>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Today?</h2>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>This has to be a really long line to show you what I mean, so although I tried to be brief, it turned into a longer discussion.</h2>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the result you're after. How about changing `display: inline-block;` to `display: inline;`?

Comment: I doubt that `h2` is appropriately sued here. It is a headline not meant for text.

Comment: @j08691 `display: inline` doesn't help with this specific issue. @tacoshy I agree, but I am stuck using an `h2` for other legacy reasons. The problem still exists if I take those tags out completely.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the final result should look like, as well as how doesn't inline solve the issue?

Comment: @j08691 When you run the code snippet, you can see that there are two lines of text. The first includes the first three list items placed side-by-side/inline. I would like the fourth list item to also be placed side-by-side/inline, i.e. the word "This" should directly follow the word "Today?" inline, as if there were one paragraph instead of two.

Comment: Why did you accept an answer when you told me that display: inline doesn't help with your situation?

Comment: @j08691 I will look at this again this evening when I have some time. I may have made a mistake and you may be right.

Comment: @j08691 My apologies for the mistake. I unchecked the answer. If you would like to answer, I could read it and accept it. I know this is non-standard, and I admit to making a mistake. This is the best solution I can think of.

Comment: @interwebjill Alright, so going back to my original question, why not change display: inline-block; to display: inline;? You said "display: inline doesn't help with this specific issue"  but didn't say how or why

Answer (score 1):

You get what you want by using `display:inline` for `h2`tag:

```css
    ul {
        width: 100%;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    li, h2 {
        display: inline;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    
    li::after {
    content: '\00a0 '; /* To give a space between li elements */
    }
```

```html
 <ul>
        <li>
            <h2>Hello!</h2>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>How are you?</h2>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Today?</h2>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>This has to be a really long line to show you what I mean, so although I tried to be brief, it turned into a longer discussion.</h2>
        </li>
 </ul>
```